# how does an isp provide public ip to the client

Tags: isp

how does the isp provide public ip
from where did they get the public ip registerd

Answer (score 1):

The same way you do it internally, but with public IPs and BGP to other providers... Oh and some really big routers. Except that they have to register their IPs with IANA local registries or another provider known as a LIR(local internet registry.).